# Trying to build SFML on Windows 8 with Cmake. But Cmake is failing

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

I am trying to build SFML on Windows 8, and using cmake to create a visual studio 2010 project. The program is giving me an error, and I am not sure what to do with it.

Any help? Here is the output from cmake.

```
The C compiler identification is unknown
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake:31 (try_compile):
  Cannot copy output executable

    ''

  to destination specified by COPY_FILE:

    'C:/Users/Zachary/Downloads/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/2.8.10.2/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin'

  Unable to find the executable at any of:

    C:/Users/Zachary/Downloads/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTryCompileExec3899792351.exe
    C:/Users/Zachary/Downloads/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTryCompileExec3899792351.exe
    C:/Users/Zachary/Downloads/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Development/cmTryCompileExec3899792351.exe

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:75 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ABI)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (project)


Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake:52 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "C:/Users/Zachary/Downloads/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/2.8.10.2/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin"
  cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:75 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ABI)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (project)


Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake:31 (try_compile):
  Cannot copy output executable

    ''

  to destination specified by COPY_FILE:

    'C:/Users/Zachary/Downloads/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/2.8.10.2/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin'

  Unable to find the executable at any of:

    C:/Users/Zachary/Downloads/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTryCompileExec1219109554.exe
    C:/Users/Zachary/Downloads/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTryCompileExec1219109554.exe
    C:/Users/Zachary/Downloads/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Development/cmTryCompileExec1219109554.exe

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:68 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ABI)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (project)


Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake:52 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "C:/Users/Zachary/Downloads/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/2.8.10.2/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin"
  cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:68 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ABI)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (project)


Looking for sys/types.h
Looking for sys/types.h - found
Looking for stdint.h
Looking for stdint.h - found
Looking for stddef.h
Looking for stddef.h - found
Check size of void*
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckTypeSize.cmake:92 (try_compile):
  Cannot copy output executable

    ''

  to destination specified by COPY_FILE:

    'C:/Users/Zachary/Downloads/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/SIZEOF_VOID_PTR.bin'

  Unable to find the executable at any of:

    C:/Users/Zachary/Downloads/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTryCompileExec3928396189.exe
    C:/Users/Zachary/Downloads/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTryCompileExec3928396189.exe
    C:/Users/Zachary/Downloads/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Development/cmTryCompileExec3928396189.exe

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckTypeSize.cmake:177 (__check_type_size_impl)
  cmake/Config.cmake:7 (check_type_size)
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/Config.cmake:13 (message):
  Unsupported architecture
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (include)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Are you executing CMake from a Visual Studio 2010 command prompt and/or using the `-G"Visual Studio 10"` CMake flag?

Comment: this is from CMake-gui. But I have tried cmake -G"Visual Stuido 10" from the Visual Stuio 2010 command prompt as well.

Comment: Something's wrong with your compiler setup. This error happens before any SFML-specific stuff has even started. Can you even compile a trivial example such as the CMake tutorial? Which CMake version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Start terminal as Administrator.
helped me, with cygwin.